# How can I get MIBs list from a remote server by using PHP?

Tags: php, snmp, remote-server, mib, oid

I am working on a project that involves SNMP. Basically I need to construct MIB and OID tree in PHP.

I know that there are programs that do this already, but I am trying to implement my own version to incorporate with my webapp.

**What I know**: I am familiar with php SNMP function. I can do SNMPWALk to get OIDs and such. Unfortunately there is no function that I know of that finds all MIBs and parses them.

**What I need**:
Get all MIB docs first from remote server, then based on each docs get their Objects.
At the end my tree will have this structure:

```
+ mib-doc1 |
           - obc1
           - obj2
+ mib-doc2 |
           - obj1
           - obj2
           - obj3
```

and so on...

**I also know**:

1. From the actual server I can get all the MIB directories:

> $net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs

2. I can also get list of all MIB docs:

> $snmpwalk -mALL -v1 cpublic ip

**I have 2 questions.**

1. How can I get list of all MIB docs from a remote server?
2. Is there an easier way (with known functions), to parse each MIB to get Objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of modules, see **if** your manager supports SNMPv2-MIB::sysORTable. This does not help you find the MIB files of course, but tells you what is supposed to be supported.

Quoting specs, `sysORTable` is:

> "The (conceptual) table listing the capabilities of the
>   local SNMP application acting as a command responder with respect to
>   various MIB modules. SNMP entities having dynamically-configurable
>   support of MIB modules will have a dynamically-varying number of
>   conceptual rows."

Here is what I get for a standard Linux host :

```
snmptable -M +.  -m +ALL -v 2c -c public -Pu -Ci  <some ipaddr>  SNMPv2-MIB::sysORTable
SNMP table: SNMPv2-MIB::sysORTable

 index                                        sysORID                                              sysORDescr  sysORUpTime
     1          SNMP-MPD-MIB::snmpMPDMIBObjects.3.1.1         The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching. 0:0:00:00.30
     2       SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmMIBCompliance         The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching. 0:0:00:00.30
     3 SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpFrameworkMIBCompliance                   The SNMP Management Architecture MIB. 0:0:00:00.30
     4                            SNMPv2-MIB::snmpMIB                      The MIB module for SNMPv2 entities 0:0:00:00.30
     5                                TCP-MIB::tcpMIB         The MIB module for managing TCP implementations 0:0:00:00.30
     6                                     IP-MIB::ip The MIB module for managing IP and ICMP implementations 0:0:00:00.30
     7                                UDP-MIB::udpMIB         The MIB module for managing UDP implementations 0:0:00:00.30
     8        SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB::vacmBasicGroup               View-based Access Control Model for SNMP. 0:0:00:00.30
```