# Dynamically traversing MIB to find OIDs to extract information

Tags: networking, network-programming, snmp, mib

I am currently attempting to pull specific information from the MIBs of a couple of devices.

These will mainly be Cisco devices, I was wondering if there were any common OIDs for all devices I can query from, or would they need to be individually hard coded in a config file? Or maybe anyway I can dynamically search for these OIDs?

Correct me if I am wrong, but to my understanding, the MIB set for each device type is different and there are very few common elements within them, most of which will be manufacturer specific?

I am trying to retrieve things like

- CPU usage
- HDD free space
- uptime
- etc...

Comment: Yes, all nodes implement different sets of MIBs. However, many nodes will implement the same standard MIBs. There are two ways to find out: 1. SNMP walk the nodes and compare the output 2. Ask the vendors/documentation about which MIBs are implemented.

Comment: Thanks,  can you put your comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Removed #SNMP tag, as this question is for general SNMP practice and not bind to a single SNMP framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all devices implement different sets of MIBs. However, many devices will implement the same standard MIBs, so there may be common variables that you could poll from all of them, particularly if they're from a single vendor.

There are two fairly straighforward ways to find out the MIB set implemented by a device:

1. SNMP walk it and compare the output
2. Ask the vendors/documentation about which MIBs are implemented.

Some devices also store the MIB files on their file system, making it possible to fetch the canonical list from there, but that's not applicable in 100% of the cases.

Comment: A less straightforward but sometimes useful way to see what device supports is the SNMPv2-MIB::sysORTable - a table listing the capabilities of the local SNMP application - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870754/449347

Comment: True, k1eran. Assuming the vendor remembers to implement that MIB correctly. Which they really should do, but sometimes forget.